# Array field in rails eliminating duplicate elements on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

When editing a form field that is a two-dimensional array, if the edit results in any two elements being equal, the second of the alike elements is deleted. It is if I had called uniq on the array. I'm looking for clues as to why this is happening and any thoughts on preventing it from occurring.

<**EDIT**> I should have included the error that is coming back from Postgres... PG::InvalidTextRepresentation - ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions

Background:
I'm using Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.1.1p76 and Postgres 9.3.5. I have an Invoice model that saves data from other models by way of CompileInvoice, a single class service that runs when a project is finished and all of the appropriate labor and materials figures have been updated. The purpose of the Invoice model is to consolidate data from a number of models into a single record and allow for it to be stored in an semi-immutable form. I say semi-immutable because my customer's accounting department wants a single opportunity to view an invoice and make corrections before it is sent to the customer. My problem relates to this edit.

The field in question is "materials" and it was created as follows:

`add_column :invoices, :materials, :text, array: true, default: []`

In my Invoice model, I use for following getter and setter to retain the two-dimensional configuration of the array:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
(...)
    def materials_list= input
    list =[]

    input.each do |key, value|
      list << value
    end

    self.materials = list.each_slice(4).to_a
  end

  def materials_list
    self.materials
  end
end
```

My invoice_params method in the InvoicesController looks like this:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
(...)
  private
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(
        (...)
        :materials_total
        ).tap do |whitelisted|
          whitelisted[:materials_list] = params[:invoice][:materials_list]
        end
    end
end
```

I am aware that normally I would want to declare that materials_list is an array by using `:materials_list => []` but when I do that (either as a part of my whitelisted block or within the permitted parameters) any changes to the data do not make it through to the model.

This is the relevant html from edit.html.erb:

```
thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Extended Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <%= f.fields_for :materials_list do |mm| %>
    <% @invoice.materials_list.try(:each) do |element| %>
      <tr>
        <% element.try(:each) do |cell| %>
          <td>
            <%= mm.text_field cell, :value => cell, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

This is a request parameter that now has eleven elements rather than the twelve that make up the three four element arrays within the array -- dropping the quantity in "one" from 2 to 1 which makes the third and fourth elements of the first array equal.

```
"materials_list"=>{"one"=>"one", "1"=>"1", "3.01"=>"3.01", "two"=>"two",
"3"=>"3", "4.01"=>"4.01", "12.03"=>"12.03", "three"=>"three", "4"=>"4",
"5.01"=>"5.01", "20.04"=>"20.04"},
```

This is the array in IRB:

```
materials:
  [["one", "2", "3.01", "6.02"],
  ["two", "3", "4.01", "12.03"],
  ["three", "4", "5.01", "20.04"]]
```

I can edit this array all day long and it only breaks when I make two elements equal. As stated above, it's as if uniq was being called on the array.

Comment: Unclear for me why postgres behaves in this way, but could you work around this by simply updating the quantity field (doubling it I suppose) instead of trying to store 2 identical "element arrays" within the materials_list column?

Comment: The results are the same. Since asking the question, I've added javascript to update the appropriate cell when changing the value of another and had identical results. 

The Postgres error is indicative of the missing element. Postgres won't save a multidimensional array unless the subarrays are of equal length. The form submits the field as a one dimensional array and the setter method in the model slices it into subarrays of four elements each. When there is a duplicate array element, the form is deleting it and the last subarray is left with only three elements.

Comment: Okay, I'm making some progress. The post params didn't feel right to me. They should read something like "materials_list"=>{["1","2","3","4"]} or perhaps even nested like "materials_list"=>{[["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"]]} instead of "materials_list"=>{"one"=>"one", "1"=>"1"...}. This explains why the duplicate elements are deleted -- it is really duplicate keys that are at issue here. I'll next focus on correcting the format of the post params to properly reflect an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a solution to my problem though I'm open to other ideas as I'm not sure it is really the best solution. In my comments, I noted that post params returned an array of hashes. I ended up setting the keys to the hashes with the array index in order to avoid duplication and relying on the materials_list method in the Invoice model to convert the hashes to an array prior to saving.

I also needed to abandon using a table in the view as I no longer have an array of arrays over which to iterate within the view.

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row" id="miscMaterialsTable">
  <% @invoice.misc_materials_list.try(:each_with_index) do |cell, i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :misc_materials_list do |array_form| %>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <%= array_form.text_field [i], :value => cell, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

invoice.rb

```
def misc_materials_list= input
  list =[]

  input.each do |key, value|
    list << value
  end

  self.misc_materials = list.each_slice(4).to_a
end

def misc_materials_list
  self.misc_materials.flatten
end
```